# Java/Javascript read content-disposition file content

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, http, content-disposition

For my web site, I need to get some data from an URL whose response headers contains Content-Disposition attribute which forces me to download the file. I would like to know how I can read the content of the file without downloading the file to disk and do I/O to read it.
Doing so in either Java or JavaScript would be fine.

Comment: most likely you will be using java since you don't want to downloaad the file and javascript is more for client-side scripting..

Comment: @Sionnach733 I am ok with using java, but just need to know the way to do it without downloading the actual file and do I/O to read it

Answer (score 0):

Content-Disposition is just advisory. If you use a non-browser client (Java, curl, wget...) and do a GET request, you can just do whatever you want.

(I guess this means your question isn't sufficiently specific)