# Read file of content-disposition with java

Tags: java, http, content-disposition

I am developing a web-app that needs to query an ontology through a REST-API. 
If I call the API through the browser, it opens a pop-up "Save As" through which I can save the file. 
This is because the header of the response contains:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = query-result.srx
```

The problem is that I would like to receive the file within my web-app without using the browser.
The web-app is write on java and I use Apache HttpClient for send and receive, HTTP request and response:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

If I try to get the entity's content:

```
httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()
```

It return a useless value.

It 's something that you can do with this library, or should I use another library.

I found another question similar to mine but no one answered.

[java-javascript-read-content-disposition-file-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175946/java-javascript-read-content-disposition-file-content)

Thanks to all who answer me!

Comment: Define "useless value".

Comment: If I use this function `IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8")` the string returned is: `BRTR`.

Comment: Can you obtain an HTTP trace?

Comment: Now I found the solution but the problem was in the query that I sent to ontology. Because I do not have 10 reputation I can not answer my question up at 6:32 PM. Thank for you interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the error was in the query that I used the REST API. So the operations I did in Java were correct. With the command

```
httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()
```

you can take the content that is returned even if this file is described in the content-disposition.

Thanks to @Julian Reschke